# how to make auto complete display result from label or id

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I work on php sales program

I have an input to select product from `autocomplete` list

I simply want to display search results for the product I entered with the `product name` or whith the `product barcode` without displaying the barcode

my php code for the source array is:

```
$source = array();
$data = mysql_query("select * from items");
while($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    $array[id] = $d['id'];
    $array[value] = $d['product_name'];
    $array[lable] = $d['product_barcode'];
    array_push($source,$array);
}
$array = json_encode($source);
```

my js code is:

```
$('#main_item').autocomplete({
      source: <?=$array?>,
      select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.pur_items_id').last().val(ui.item.id);
            $('.item_name').text(ui.item.value);
       }
});
```

what I need is , when `barcode` is entered autocomplete shows product with that barcode
without displaying the barcode in autocomplete search results.

Answer (score 0):

ok thank you every one

I came up with a solution

if there is any way to improve that solution and make it better please share

my code :

```
source = <?=$array?>;
    barcode = new Array;
    jQuery.map( source, function( n , i) {
      barcode[i] = ( n.lable );
    });
    $('#main_item').autocomplete({
          source: source,
          select: function(event, ui) {
                $('.pur_items_id').last().val(ui.item.id);
                $('.item_name').text(ui.item.value);
           }
    }).keyup(function(e,u){
        var item = $.inArray($(this).val(),barcode);
        if(item != -1)
        {
            $('.pur_items_id').last().val(source[item]['id']);
            $('.item_name').text(source[item]['value']);
        }
    });
```